# Re-arrange array to combine overlapping results

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm using datetime to store dates of when new data is entered per provider.  Using the following query to pull the results:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS addedCount,
date(date_added) AS dateAdded,
provider_name as provider 
FROM `table` WHERE `table`.`id` IN (SELECT `table`.`id` FROM `table` 
WHERE     `table`.`active` = '1') 

GROUP BY dateAdded
ORDER BY dateAdded DESC
```

The array looks like this:

```
array(1343) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
        ["addedCount"]=>
        string(1) "2"
        ["dateAdded"]=>
        string(10) "2012-03-03"
        ["provider"]=>
        string(5) "Provider_1"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
        ["addedCount"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["dateAdded"]=>
        string(10) "2012-03-03"
        ["provider"]=>
        string(5) "Provider_1"
   }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
      ["addedCount"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["dateAdded"]=>
      string(10) "2012-03-03"
      ["provider"]=>
      string(5) "Provider_2"
   }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
      ["addedCount"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["dateAdded"]=>
      string(10) "2012-03-03"
      ["provider"]=>
      string(5) "Provider_2"
```

I need the results to count the total of "addedCount" where "dateAdded" and "provider" match so that the final array looks like:

```
addedCount  dateAdded   provider
3           2012-03-03  provider_1
2           2012-03-03  provider_2
```

I've tried tirelessly searching SO and rebuilding the arrays, but after many hours spent, I ended up rebuilding the array in its original form,

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the data as indexe in order to group similar data for example:

```
$groupArray = array();
foreach ( $providerArr as $provider )
{
    // Using the grouping info (date & name) as a key to our grouping array

    $key = $provider[ 'dateAdded' ] . $provider[ 'provider' ];
    if ( !isset( $groupArray[ $key ] ) )
    {
        // Our grouping array does not have the specific combination of date & name yet
        // so save the first occurance of data for this combination.

        $groupArray[ $key ] = $provider;
    }
    else
    {
        // The unique combination of date & name already exists so just update the count

        $groupArray[ $key ][ 'addedCount' ] += $provider[ 'addedCount' ];
    }
}

// Now print

foreach ( $groupArray as $data )
{
    echo( "{$data[ 'addedCount' ]} - {$data[ 'dateAdded'} - {$data[ '$provider' ]}<br/>" );
}
```

Comment: excellent! thank you!  I made a few tiny adjustments to output the data into another array and its now exactly as i need it.  Thanks again!